# Restore Point area getting deleted

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, multi-boot, system-restore

I'm running a multi-boot scenario with partitions split between Windows 7 32-bit, Windows 7 64-bit, and a common data partition (which happens to store the user hives for each OS instance).

For some reason, on one particular machine (a HP Pavilion notebook) the restore points get trashed after a reboot.  I can create them (both manually and automatically), but after some (but not all) reboots the restore points get trashed.  I have all three partitions set (on both OSs) to hold restore information.  This setup has worked successfully on other machines for at least 12 months.

I'm out of ideas; I need the restore points as I do "bleeding edge" stuff and they've saved my bacon on other machines in the past. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you perhaps have any scheduled clean up/clear out tasks set up?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your comment...  I do manual backup of files (using shadow copy) but the restore points are killed on next boot.

I've found an MSDN article (see answer below) which may or may not be relevant.

Comment: By next boot I mean any boot - even into the same OS instance.  So, technically, it's not a multi-boot problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following MSDN article which covers multi-boot and Restore Points (but not quite my situation):

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926185/en-us

In any event, it is only on one machine (in the main) where I have this problem.  Both OSs are Windows 7 - one 32-bit, the other 64-bit.  I've now turned off System Restore for the 64-bit instance to see if that changes anything.